# Projections from geoserver REST

Tags: geoserver

It is possible to get all allowed projections from geoserver REST API ?

I mean all this projections that allowed here...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get that information via the REST api but it is included in the WMS getCapabilities document - http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities